# Using PySimpleGUI, how do I run a 'FocusOut' event without the cursor moving to the next element automatically?

Tags: pysimplegui

I am attaching an extract from a larger program using PySimpleGUI. I am using FocusOut to test whether anything has been entered in an Inputbox (or whether a date has been selected). Each test on its own works well giving a popup message and then returning focus to the empty element. A problem arises when a second and third etc element is added. Then, if you fail to enter something in the first element you get 2 or 3 successive popups before focus is returned to the first one. Obviously there is something missing which would make each element complete its event before the next event is triggered. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
enter code here

from datetime import date

import PySimpleGUI as sg

TodayDt=date.today()
print("Today's date is " + str(TodayDt))


layout=[
        
[sg.T("Today's date is:"),sg.InputText(TodayDt, size=(10, 10), key='_TODAYCAL_')],
[sg.T("Select new transaction date:"),sg.CalendarButton('Calendar',  target='-IN4-', key='_DATE_',format='%Y-%m-%d'),sg.In(key='-IN4-', size=(10,1))],
[sg.T("Fuel quantity (in litres):"),sg.In(key="_FUELQUANT_",size=(10,1),enable_events=True),sg.T("Fuel amount N$:"),sg.In(key="_FUELAMNT_", size=(10,1),enable_events=True)],
[sg.T("Oil quantity (in millilitres:"),sg.In(key="_OILQUANT_",size=(10,1)),sg.T("Oil amount N$:"),sg.In(key="_OILAMNT_",size=(10,1))],
    
]

window = sg.Window('My Vehicle Logbook', layout, finalize=True)

iFuelQuant=window['_FUELQUANT_']
iFuelQuant.bind('<FocusOut>','FOCUS OUT')
fFuelAmnt=window['_FUELAMNT_']
fFuelAmnt.bind('<FocusOut>','FOCUS OUT')
dNewDt=window['-IN4-']
dNewDt.bind('<FocusOut>','FOCUS OUT')

while True:
    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Cancel':     # if user closes window or clicks cancel
        break

    
    if event=='-IN4-FOCUS OUT':

        text=values['-IN4-']
        print(text)

        if text=='':
            sg.popup("Warning","You haven't selected a date")

            window.find_element('_DATE_')
            window.find_element('_DATE_').SetFocus()
            continue

    if event=='_FUELQUANT_' and values['_FUELQUANT_']:

        try:

            fFuelQuant=float(values['_FUELQUANT_'])
            fFuelQuant="{: .2f}".format(float(fFuelQuant))#(in_as_float)
            print(fFuelQuant)

        except:

            if len(values['_FUELQUANT_'])== 1 and values['_FUELQUANT_'][0]=='-':

                sg.popup()

                continue

            window['_FUELQUANT_'].update(values['_FUELQUANT_'][:-1])



    
    if event=='_FUELQUANT_FOCUS OUT':

        try:

            fFuelQ = (values['_FUELQUANT_'])
            fFuelQ = "{: .2f}".format(float(fFuelQ))
            window.find_element('_FUELQUANT_').update(fFuelQ)
                
            print(fFuelQ)
            continue    

        except:

            if len(fFuelQ) == 0:
                sg.popup("Warning!!!","You have not entered a fuel quantity")
                #window.find_element('_FUELQUANT_').refresh('')
                window.find_element('_FUELQUANT_').SetFocus()
                #continue
    
    if event=='_FUELAMNT_' and values['_FUELAMNT_']:

        try:

            fFuelAmnt=float(values['_FUELAMNT_'])
            fFuelAmnt="{: .2f}".format(float(fFuelAmnt))#(in_as_float)
            print(fFuelQuant)

        except:

            if len(values['_FUELAMNT_'])== 1 and values['_FUELAMNT_'][0]=='-':

                sg.popup()

                continue

            window['_FUELAMNT_'].update(values['_FUELAMNT_'][:-1])

    if event=='_FUELAMNT_FOCUS OUT':

        try:

            fFuelAmnt = (values['_FUELAMNT_'])
            fFuelAmnt = "{: .2f}".format(float(fFuelAmnt))
            window.find_element('_FUELAMNT_').update(fFuelAmnt)
                
            print(fFuelAmnt)
            continue

        except:

            if len(fFuelAmnt) == 0:
                sg.popup("Warning!!!","You have not entered a fuel amount")

                #window.find_element('_FUELQUANT_').refresh('')
                window.find_element('_FUELAMNT_').SetFocus()
                #continue

    

window.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> FocusIn, FocusOut
>
> The FocusIn and FocusOut events are generated whenever the keyboard focus changes. A FocusOut event is sent to the old focus window, and a FocusIn event is sent to the new one.
> In addition, if the old and new focus windows do not share a common parent, “virtual crossing” focus events are sent to the intermediate windows in the hierarchy. Thus a FocusIn event indicates that the target window or one of its descendants has acquired the focus, and a FocusOut event indicates that the focus has been changed to a window outside the target window's hierarchy.
>
> The keyboard focus may be changed explicitly by a call to focus, or implicitly by the window manager.

So the focus out event will be generated when you call `sg.popup` or `sg.set_focus`, then event will be generated again and again, that's why the popup window shown again and again.

Here's the short code to demo it, five inputs but only 2nd and 3rd one check it empty entry.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def popup(*args, elem=None):
    for element in elements:
        element.unbind('<FocusOut>')
    window.refresh()                        # Make unbind effect
    layout = [
        [sg.Text('\n'.join(args))],
        [sg.Button('OK')],
    ]
    sg.Window('Popup', layout).read(close=True)
    if elem:
        elem.set_focus()
        window.refresh()                    # Make set_focus effect
    for element in elements:
        element.bind('<FocusOut>','+FOCUS OUT')

layout=[[sg.Input(key=f'-IN{i}-')] for i in range(5)]

window = sg.Window('My Vehicle Logbook', layout, finalize=True)
keys = ('-IN1-', '-IN2-')
elements = [window[key] for key in keys]
for element in elements:
    element.bind('<FocusOut>','+FOCUS OUT')

while True:
    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Cancel':     # if user closes window or clicks cancel
        break
    elif event.endswith("+FOCUS OUT"):
        print(event)
        key = event.split('+')[0]
        if values[key] == '':
            popup("Warning", f"Blank entry in {key} is not accept !", elem=window[key])

window.close()
```

Comment: Jason Yang,thank you for your very prompt reply. I have applied your suggestion but it still isn't working differently. I am not sure how to respond further to show how I have modified the code. Should I edit my original post by substituting the "old" code with the new so that you can look at it for me? Kind regards.

Comment: Update as above.

Comment: Thank you Jason Yang. Brilliant solution. I adapted it to my program and it works perfectly. I have learnt a lot from analysing your code.